# rich:dataScroller won't reset at page 1 on a new search

Tags: java, datatables, xhtml, richfaces

i'm facing a problem with component rich:dataScroller:

when i trigger an actionListener to fill a datatable with new data and the table (made with component rich:dataTable) is currently at page > 1, the table updated will update correctly but not pointing at page #1 as expected.

is there any way to reset component dataScroller or to tell the table to reset its pagination in that situation?

thanks in advice,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Page won't change automatically (e.g on filtering). But you can do it yourself. For example:

In JavaScript:

```
RichFaces.component(scrollerName).first();
```

In Java:

```
UIDataScroller scroller = (UIDataScroller) findComponent(scrollerClientId);
if (scroller.getPage() > 1) {
    DataScrollEvent resetScrollerEvent = new DataScrollEvent(scroller,
            Integer.toString(scroller.getPage()), "1", 1);
    scroller.broadcast(resetScrollerEvent);
}
```